# Sticky Footer in Skeleton based Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying to add a "sticky footer" to my web site based on skeleton but I can't get it to work correctly. I am doing this based on the instruction on this website: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html. In Chrome I get an extra pixel or two in the height of the page which result in a vertical scrollbar and in IE the main container becomes left-aligned.

Any idea how I should implement this properly based on Skeleton? Thank you Dave for the great work!

Comment: show the demo. we are not telepaths.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8w5pd9n5/... Heres the Demo

Comment: want to make the Footer Sticky... And Responsive

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521642/custom-cms-with-with-ability-to-change-themes-from-admin-panel please start selecting answers for your questions instead of simply commenting with "thank you".

Answer (score 5):

I've developed a dead-simple pure-CSS solution to this now, [located here](https://github.com/mahmoud/skeleton_sticky_footer). The solution is based on Skeleton 2.0.4 and basically consists of creating two separate skeleton containers/rowstacks: One for the header/body, another for the sticky footer.

Comment: Sure. You can upvote and accept the answer if it works well for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var footerHeight = $('.footer').height()+30; // "+30" footer on to add space
   $('body').css('margin-bottom',footerHeight);
});
```

Css

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height:100%;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7bbc42;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to have the footer only come into view if the user tries to scroll down to the very bottom of the page, put everything that goes above the footer into a single div that has a min-height of '100vh'.